# python program for entering informations

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I am writing program that ask to enter names of people and their phone numbers in the dictionary until the user enters "stop". At the end, the program should ask for a specific name for which you would like a printout of the phone number. If this name is not in the dictionary, program need to display “I cannot find the name. Please try again: «. If he finds it, he displays the corresponding telephone number. This is what I wrote:

```
dict = {}

name = input('Enter name: ')

while name != '':
    if not name in dict:
phone_number = int(input('Enter phone number: '))
print(f'{name}: {phone_number}')
dict[name] = phone_number
name = input('Enter name: ')
if name in dict:
    print(dict[name])
else:
    break
print(dict)

name2 = input('Enter a name to print the phone number: ')

while name2 != '':
    if not name2 in dict:
        name2 = input('Enter a name to print the phone number: ')
    else:
        print(f'Phone number of {name} is {phone_number}.')
        break
```

I don't know how to fix it to work properly, I mean so that it will comply with the my instructions. I would be very happy if someone give me advices

Comment: What's the problem/error?

Comment: i can't redesign it to fit the instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design of your program is not following what you need to do. Follow below steps to re-design it:

1. Run a loop and ask name and phone number. Store it in dict, and then repeat.
2. Stop this loop if user enters 'stop'. In other words, run this loop until user enters 'stop'.
3. Run a loop again and ask for a name (to display that person's phone number if in your dict).
4. If name is found, display phone number and exit the loop.
5. If name not found, display your message and ask. Repeat loop on point 3, until name is found.

Below code does the steps I explained above in points.

```
phonebook = {}

name = input('Enter name: ')

while name != 'stop':    # run the loop until user enters stop
    phone_number = int(input('Enter phone number: '))
    print(f'{name}: {phone_number}')
    phonebook[name] = phone_number
    name = input('Enter name: ')
    
print(phonebook)

while True:   # run the loop indefinitely to keep asking name, use break to force exit when match
    name2 = input('Enter a name to print the phone number: ')
    if name2 in phonebook:
        phone_number = phonebook[name2]
        print(f'Phone number of {name2} is {phone_number}.')
        break     # since match was found,  exit the loop now
    else:
        print(f'I cannot find the name. Please try again')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and help! Your explanation helped me a lot in understanding the code.